# The plugin Comments does not work for new facebook-accounts

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

I use the plugin Comments on my website.
It seems that new facebook accounts can not fully publish comments on it. I have tested with an account (14 days old) and a new one today.
Comments published by this accounts are only visible for themselves, with a browser logged in on facebook or friends of the account in facebook.
If the reader is not logged on facebook and/or are not a friend of the new account that published the comment, it does not show.

Answer (score 1):

the reason for this is that FB considers new accounts to be spammy, so you must moderate and approve each new message! Hope this helps.